# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322) -- union of conditional type not working

Tags: typescript, conditional-operator, union-types

The following type `GetFieldType` deduces the type of a property at a given path of an object (I'm using a simplified version which still produces the error):

```ts
type GetFieldType<TObject, TPath> = TPath extends keyof TObject ? TObject[TPath] : undefined;

type Route<TObject> = {
  [TPath in string]: Extract<GetFieldType<TObject, TPath>, boolean | number | string>;
};

interface Item {
  foo: string
}

const r: Route<Item> = {
  "foo": "string"  // type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)
//^^^^^
}
```

It seems like the error is related to `GetFieldType` being a conditional type, but I'm not sure what to make of it.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwDECWEA2ATAKuCAeTA8gEYBWEAxsADRSYAKAhsABYB8UAvLYy1BAB7AIAO3QBnKAGsIIAPYAzWsTKUoAfiWkKwANr0mzALpQAXFACuoiPKTCI6ANwBYAFCvQkKACVZ5ofmVtdi4Ab1coKD0eZihbKDFgACdbAHNDMwBRQUSGSlw4RBQMbEgArUoafRZWGiJZWVQIBmEoAB8oYXMAWyIIRLb4pNTWZxcAX1HXWyFE%20VzoAEkhLqgwlwj5erME5OEU1zHXV3JZYQSoRLMfPzwliC7g1fCoACJN2RezF53Ul4OgA)

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that the indexer type `[TPath in string]` is trying to cover any possible string. You need to consider the broad scope.

```
type GetFieldType<TObject, TPath extends keyof TObject> = TObject[TPath];

type RouteKeys<TObject> = {
  [TPath in keyof TObject]: GetFieldType<TObject, TPath> extends boolean | number | string ? GetFieldType<TObject, TPath> : never;
};

interface Item {
  foo: string;
}

const r: RouteKeys<Item> = {
  foo: "string",  // now it's fine
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwDECWEA2ATAKuCAeTA8gEYBWEAxsADRSYAKAhsABZQQAewEAdugM5QA1hBAB7AGa1iZSgD4oAXimkKwANr0mzALoBuALAAoI6EhQASqICuXANIi%20%20aavlKA3kahQNjFlCTcQiISyjLA2gBcsPDIaFg4TiqUNJos8hxcvAJEoqKoEAyBAD5Q3FYAtkQQAE5QJXzA1QEA5lAA-NGIKBjYkIlhKb7M8lHcEABuNQaGAL7TRgFc1eIM5NAAklzlUB6GXuK5UQ1N3M3TM0ZG5KLcDVDVUZY2EPYgjpsQ5a47nlAHolEAETHFqAmhQAD0ENKogA7v5gAByATiAIQIwXQxAA)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that `keyof TObject` won't be enough for my needs, as `TPath` may be any path of properties of `TObject`, like `foo.bar`